# How to send an CLI argument to a SBT task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I was programming some ScalaTest tests and I tagged some tests with a custom tag `Expensive`. Then I wanted to execute the test with sbt and a `-l com.company.Expensive` to ignore the tagged tests.

After that I try to run something like:

```
sbt -l com.company.Expensive test
sbt test -l com.company.Expensive
sbt "test -l com.company.Expensive"
```

And none of them work.

On Intellij IDEA I can specify the ScalaTest argument

[image: -l com.company.Expensive]

And it works as expected, ignoring Expensive tags (It is really receiving the -l parameter).

How can I send it to sbt through CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sbt [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Test+Framework+Arguments):

> Test Framework Arguments
>
> Arguments to the test framework may be provided on the command line to the `testOnly` tasks following a `--` separator. For example:
>
> ```
> testOnly org.example.MyTest -- -verbosity 1
> ```

In your case, use the following:

```
testOnly test.package.* -- -l com.company.Expensive
```

Substitute `test.package.*` with the appropriate glob or fully qualified test name.

Comment: So, at the end something like `sbt "testOnly -- -l com.company.Expensive"` should work?